# flyway:Unable to create schema ``: Incorrect database name ''

Tags: flyway

While trying to execute the compile flyway:migrate goals I face the following exception

com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to create schema ``: Incorrect database name ''

this is how my pom.xml looks like

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</url>
                <user>root</user>
                <password>mysql</password>
                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <!-- <schemas>
                    <schema>flywaymetadata</schema>
                    <schema>test</schema>
                </schemas> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I have a test.sql in resources/db/migration which is a backup sql script with a single schema and a single table within.

Please guide me here.. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There are two issues here:

- You are missing the database name as part of the jdbc url (ex: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb)
- Flyway could do a better job at detecting this and providing you with a more meaningful error message

Please fix the first and file an issue for the second :-)

Also you should name your script `V1__test.sql` and place it under `src/main/resources/db/migration`.

You can then migrate your DB using `mvn compile flyway:migrate`

And remember, you have to create the database first using the tool of your choice. You can do this with this SQL statement: `CREATE DATABASE test;`. Flyway handles only the schema creation, not database creation.

Comment: I have added the dbname to the url <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</url>  and renamed the file in migration folder to V1__test.sql on executing the compile flyway:migrate goals I get the following exception com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource: Unknown database 'test'

Comment: You have to create the database first using the tool of your choice. You can do this with this SQL statement: CREATE DATABASE test; Flyway only handles schema creation not database creation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about db/schema and what flyway assumes exists. Because schemas and databases are the same thing in mysql,  this was somewhat confusing as you can actually get flyway to create a database in mysql if you leave the database name off of the connection string and only specify it in the list of schemas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a MySQL database as well (5.7.x), and am running migrations via Java. I had to specify the schemas and other configs programmatically to get flyway to migrate an empty database correctly. Setting the schemas in the configuration section of the pom.xml wasn't work for me because I'm trying to run the migration directly in my application (via JUnit).

**Disclaimer:** There's definitely a cleaner way to set these configs and run the migrations, this is by no means *the* way or even the *right* way...hacky...but it works...just use with caution:

```
// The Flyway instance holds one of these bad boys under the hood...
FluentConfiguration conf = new FluentConfiguration();

// where my migrations are located within my Project
// <projectroot>/<module>/src/main/resources/db/migrations
conf.locations("classpath:db/migrations");

// my schemas, first one being the one used as the default schema
conf.schemas("defaultSchema", "schema2", "schema3", ...);

// exclude the default schema from the URL
conf.dataSource("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", "root", "uncrackable");

conf = Flyway.configure().configuration(conf);
flyway = conf.load();

// 3 days lateh...
flyway.migrate();
```

The migration worked for me using this approach. Hope this helps someone.